# Custom form for QGIS processing script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qt

I'd like to get a little more control over the layout and functionality of the user interface associated with a processing script I've created. I've made a ui file using Qt Designer, but I can't figure out how to replace the default form (which uses the ## notation to define parameters) with my new one.

I've found many examples on doing this for a plugin and for feature popups, but nothing for processing scripts.

I tried the following but I just get a blank dialog

```
from PyQt4 import uic

myForm = uic.loadUi('path_to_ui.ui')
myForm.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I made a widget class and put the original code inside it, I can get the form to show as expected. Not sure if this is the best way as I'm still quite new to PyQGIS and coding in general.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    myForm = uic.loadUi('path_to_ui.ui')
    myForm.show()
```